# my clicked number is not appear in screen in react project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, frontend, rendering

when i tried to render clicked number in screen the number is not appear.
but it does work to show in console
i don't know how to fix it the number suppose to apply in screen next to "Number:"

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";

function Clicked(props) {
  console.log(props);
  return <h1>Number:{props.value}</h1>;
}

function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={() => Clicked(props.value)}>
      {props.value}
    </button>
  );
}

function renderSquare(i) {
  return <Square value={i} />;
}

function Board() {
  const status = "Next player: X";
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(0)}
        {renderSquare(1)}
        {renderSquare(2)}
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(3)}
        {renderSquare(4)}
        {renderSquare(5)}
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        {renderSquare(6)}
        {renderSquare(7)}
        {renderSquare(8)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Game() {
  return (
    <div className="game">
      <div className="game-board">
        <Clicked />
        <Board />
      </div>
      <div className="game-info">
        <div>{/* status */}</div>
        <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<Game />);
```

there is no syntax error so I really don't get what is the point of this issue.
please help me

Answer (score 1):

In React, the way to change the view (what's displayed to the user, or laid out in the DOM) is to change *state*. When state changes, a re-render is triggered, and React reconciles the changed structure of the React elements returned with the current rendered structure (through the [virtual DOM](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-internals.html)).

Returning a value from a click handler doesn't do anything. Change some state when there's a click instead, and change the returned JSX to depend on the state.

```js
function Square({ value, setClickedNum }) {
  return (
    <button className="square" onClick={() => setClickedNum(value)}>
      {value}
    </button>
  );
}

function Board({ setClickedNum }) {
  const status = "Next player: X";
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="status">{status}</div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={0} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
        <Square value={1} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
        <Square value={2} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={3} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
        <Square value={4} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
        <Square value={5} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
      </div>
      <div className="board-row">
        <Square value={6} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
        <Square value={7} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
        <Square value={8} setClickedNum={setClickedNum} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function Game() {
  const [clickedNum, setClickedNum] = React.useState(-1);
  return (
    <div className="game">
      <div className="game-board">
        <h1>Number: {clickedNum === -1 ? 'Not clicked yet' : clickedNum}</h1>
        <Board {...{ setClickedNum }} />
      </div>
      <div className="game-info">
        <div>{/* status */}</div>
        <ol>{/* TODO */}</ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<Game />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```